# Finitely many field extensions of a given degree such that primes outside of a given subset are unramified.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

This is from JS Milne's notes on algebraic number theory.

Let $K$ be a number field, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $S$ be a finite set of primes in $K$. There are only finitely many fields $L/K$ such that primes outside of $S$ are unramified, and has degree $n$, up to isomorphism

The proof goes as follows : choose a prime of $K$ which induces an absolute value $v$. Now, for any extension $L/K$, we have $L \otimes_K \widehat{K} = \prod_{w \text{ extends } v} \widehat{L_w}$.

Therefore $disc(L/K) = \prod_{w \text{ extends } v} disc(\widehat{L_w} / \widehat{K_v})$

**First question: I don't understand how this formula is derived. $v$ appears on the right side but not on the left side. Also, why is this true? The discriminant is multiplicative in some sense? But $\prod_{w \text{ extends } v} \widehat{L_w}$ isn't a field, it's a product of fields **

If $L$ is ramified only at primes in $S$, then the product is over the primes $w$ dividing a prime $v$ in $S$, so $disc(L/K)$ is bounded

**Second question: What does this mean? Why do we only look at primes over a prime in $S$, and how does that imply the discriminant is bounded? **

Finally we use that there are only finitely many number fields with a given discriminant.